# Can I use Async CTP with .NET 3.0?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-ctp, .net-3.0

Can I use new AsyncCtpLibrary.dll with .NET 3.0? If I add this library in References, will it work? I need to use async/await/task functions in a new project.

Comment: If it's a new project, then why does it target .Net 3.0?

Answer (score 3):

The Async CTP builds upon [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) that's part of the 4.0 framework, so it's not usable with the 3.0 version of the framework.

In order to compile Async CTP code you need to install the Async CTP, because the compiler is replaced with a new compiler version capable of using the new async keywords. In order to use compiled Async CTP code it should be enough with the dlls.